# Rawpy: How to postprocess raw images WITHOUT adulterating pixel data?

Tags: python, image-processing

I need to convert raw NEF images into numpy arrays for quantitative analysis. I'm currently using rawpy to do this, but I've failed to find a combination of postprocess [parameters](https://letmaik.github.io/rawpy/api/rawpy.Params.html) that leave the pixel data untouched. (I'll be the first to admit I don't entirely understand how raw files work also...)

Here is what I have right now:

```
rawArray = raw.postprocess(demosaic_algorithm=rawpy.DemosaicAlgorithm.AHD,
                                   half_size=False,
                                   four_color_rgb=False,use_camera_wb=False,
                                   use_auto_wb=False,user_wb=(1,1,1,1),
                                   output_color=rawpy.ColorSpace.raw,
                                   output_bps=16,user_flip=None,
                                   user_black=None,user_sat=None,
                                   no_auto_bright=False,auto_bright_thr=0.01,
                                   adjust_maximum_thr=0,bright=100.0,
                                   highlight_mode=rawpy.HighlightMode.Ignore,
                                   exp_shift=None,exp_preserve_highlights=0.0,
                                   no_auto_scale=True,gamma=(2.222, 4.5),
                                   chromatic_aberration=None,
                                   bad_pixels_path=None)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Postprocessing, which means demosaicing here, will always change the original pixel values. Typically what you want is to get a linearly postprocessed image so that roughly the number of photons are in linear relation to the pixel values. You can do that with:

```
rgb = raw.postprocess(gamma=(1,1), no_auto_bright=True, output_bps=16)
```

In most cases you will not be able to get a calibrated image out where you can directly infer the number of photons that hit the sensor at each pixel. See also https://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/56232710.

Note that you can also access the raw image data via `raw.raw_image` (see also [Bayer matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_filter)) which is as close to the sensor data as you can get -- no interpolation or camera curves etc are applied here, but I would say scientifically you don't get much more than you would get with a linearly postprocessed image as described above.

Comment: Thanks! The hint about raw.raw_image is exactly what I was looking for. Now I can do my own low level calibration (automatic defective pixel detection, dust removal, pixel exact white balancing and what not). 

Comment: Hi @letmaik, thanks for your library, I use it a lot! I was looking in the suggestion you gave here but its not just performing demosaic, but also wb and other color fixes (black level? I dont know..). If I just want to perform pure demosaicing, what shall I do? Thx!